# Android Picasso random loading failures

Tags: android, image, listview, caching, picasso

I'm trying to load a bunch of images in a ListView (between 5 and 10) using Picasso for caching. 
The first time I request all the images from the server because they're not yet cached. Before using Picasso, all of them used to download ok, but now some of them fail in the download, and not always the same ones.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //ViewHolder holder = null;
        holder = null;

        if (convertView == null || !(convertView.getTag() instanceof ViewHolder)) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_app, null);

            holder.promoImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.promoAppImage);
            holder.appProgress = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appProgress);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        loadBitmap(position, holder);

        return convertView;
    }

    public void loadBitmap(int position, final ViewHolder holder) {
        final AppWithImage app = apps.get(position);

        fileLoader.setOnFileLoadedListener(this);
        Picasso.with(context).load(url).fit().tag("homeTag").into(holder.promoImage, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.d("success", "success");
                //holder.promoImage.setImageBitmap(app.getPromo());
                holder.promoImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.appProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                Log.d("error", "error");
            }
        });
    }
```

And this is what I get in the console log:

```
11-25 22:46:27.881  27096-27096/com... D/error﹕ error
11-25 22:46:27.881  27096-27096/com... D/success﹕ success
11-25 22:46:28.678  27096-27096/com... D/success﹕ success
11-25 22:46:29.022  27096-27096/com... D/success﹕ success
```

The images are quite big, between 200KB and 500KB but I don't see a reason for them to fail downloading. Is there any way to make them download one by one or at least not all at the same time?

In addition to that, the number of images was originally 5, and the first two failed but I only see one error message in the console.